# 'non-finite-function value' Error when call 'integrate' with 'maxLik' function

Tags: r, integrate

I want to use the maximum likelihood method to estimate the parameters of a function which involves integration. However, when i tried to run it, i got a message that "non-finite function value".

Here are the codes:

```
library("maxLik")

integrand <− function(x,para) 
{
  # print(para)
  
  # dv, dv_T, dn, dn_T are the actual input data, here only gives one set of value for easy debugging
  dv <- -1.4527280  
  dv_T <- 0.2038909 
  dn <- 17.5174383 
  dn_T <- 26.6993828
  
  beta10 = para[1];
  beta11 = para[2];
  beta12 = para[3];
  alpha1 = para[4];
  beta20 = para[5];
  beta21 = para[6];
  beta22 = para[7];
  alpha2 = para[8];
  
  U_Cur = exp(beta10 + beta11*dv + beta12*dn + alpha1*x);
  U_Tgt = exp(beta20 + beta21*dv_T + beta22*dn_T + alpha2*x);
  
# Update Start - 03/10/2021

   if (is.infinite(U_Cur))
      {
        if (U_Cur<0)   
        {U_Cur=-2^1000}
        else
        {U_Cur=2^1000}
      }

 if (is.infinite(U_Tgt))
      {
        if (U_Tgt <0)   
        {U_Tgt =-2^1000}
        else
        {U_Tgt =2^1000}
      }

# Update End - 03/10/2021

  # print(U_Cur)
  # print(U_Tgt)
  
  P <- (U_Cur/(U_Cur+U_Tgt))
  
  # print(P)
  
  return(P)
}


integrand2 <− function(para1) {integrate( integrand, lower = -2 , upper = 2, para=para1)$value }

MLE<-maxLik(logLik=integrand2,start=c(0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3, -0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6))
```

After debug, i find the reason of the error is the value of U_Cur or U_Tgt sometimes may be 0 or Inf.

I have no idea about how to deal with that, I really appreciate any related proposal.

===================================

EDIT:

I have update the value of U_Cur, U_Tgt, if they are (-)infinite, set their value as (-)2^1000 (the code is added in the function body above, between “# Update - 03/10/2021”).

Answer (score 0):

I could be misreading your code, but it looks like you are maximizing the following (log)likelihood:

LL = int^2_{-2} exp(5+x+theta) dx = exp(5+theta)int^2_{-2} exp(x) dx.

That likelihood will be maximized by sending theta to infinity.  Is that the log likelihood you want?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry to simplify the function too much. I've updated the simplified functions. My purpose is to estimate the value of 'para' so that U_ Cur/(U_ Cur+U_ TGT) is the largest. Through debugging, I found that the reason for the error is that U_ Cur or u_ Tgt can sometimes be inf or 0. Is there any way to avoid this error?

Comment: Maximization techniques do sometimes try values that break the likelihood.  Maybe you could modify the para function so that the U_Cur, U_Tgt, P are given a lower or upper bounds (with an if statement).  That would keep your program from crashing.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I have modified the value of U_Cur, U_Tgt, if they are (-)infinite, set their value as (-)2^1000 (i have added the detail code in the description of question). When running the program, it will report the error that "The integral is probably divergent". Is there any good way to solve it?